# If we spot n dots on a sphere (radius r), there exists two dots whose distance is under d

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, discrete-geometry

Is there any formula about $n$, $r$, $d$ at the question?

Comment: I am not convinced that this *is* unclear. Is there a minimum number $n$ such that it is impossible to place $n$ dots on a sphere whose distance is less than the diameter of the sphere? I think that it is *quite* clear after ten seconds thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to distribute points on a sphere so that the minimum distance is as big as possible is unsolved. It might be possible to get decent bounds on $d$ in terms of $n$ (and $r$), but it's unlikely that you will be able to find the best possible value of $d$ for general $n$.

See [this discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere) for some thoughts about the problem. You may also be interested in [this description of some variations of the problem](http://www.maths.unsw.edu.au/about/distributing-points-sphere).